# Assigning event handler in Delphi 2007 to all controls on the form

Tags: delphi, oop

I'm trying to create a small bit of software to mess around with drag and drop a bit. I started out with only creating TButtons dynamically and it worked fine.

However when generalizing the functionality I've run into a problem due to the 'protected' status of the OnDragDrop and OnMouseDownEvent of the base class TControl.

```
procedure TForm1.FormDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
  var
    newControl: TControl;
    selClass: TControlClass;
    ctlName: string;
    selItem: string;
  begin
    if TControl(Sender).Parent = Self then
    begin
      with TWinControl(Source) do
      begin
        Left:= X;
        Top:= Y;
        EndDrag(True); {drop the control}
      end;
    end
    else begin
      selItem:= TypeList.Items[TypeList.ItemIndex];
      selClass:= TControlClass(GetClass(selItem));

      newControl:= selClass.Create(Self);
      newControl.Parent:= Self;

      ctlName:= newControl.ClassName + IntToStr(GetControlCount(selClass));
      Delete(ctlName, 1, 1); {Remove 'T' from name}

      newControl.Name:= ctlName;
      newControl.Left:= X;
      newControl.Top:= Y;

      { TODO : assign events onDragDrop and onMouseDown}
      (*
      newControl.OnMouseDown:= @ControlMouseDown;
      newControl.OnDragDrop:= @FormDragDrop;
      *)

    end;

  end;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following declaration to your unit:

```
type
  TControlHack = class(TControl);
```

and use a type cast for the new control:

```
TControlHack(newControl).OnMouseDown := ...
```

Comment: I've used this approach several times and can vouch for it.  You can also use this method to enhance or extend any control on a form without having to create your own custom control.  You could even simplify this example with `type TControl = class (Controls.TControl);`.  All this does is trick the compiler into thinking TControl was declared within your form unit so you can access protected members.

Comment: The idea behind this hack is that a derived class has access to its anchestor's protected members and any code inside the same unit as the derived class has access to that classes protected (and private) members. Therefore it also has access to the anchestor's protected members.

Answer (score 2):

You could use RTTI, the "old style" RTTI is available via `TypInfo` [unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/TypInfo):

- use `IsPublishedProp()` to check does the class / object have property;
- use `SetMethodProp()` to assign eventhandler.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this who is using D2010 or above:

I wrote a small utility called "DelphiEventLogger" to do this exact thing: i.e. "assign an event handler to all controls on the form". It uses the newer style RTTI, which is not available in Delphi before 2010 (I believe).

It's very easy to use; just add the Unit in your Uses list and then make one procedure call.

Download is [here](http://code.google.com/p/delphieventlogger/)